# Remote Certificate Invalid randomly breaking email when nothing has changed? (AWS)

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a basic email web service that runs on one of my boxes. This box sends email using Amazon SES. It has sent 250,000 emails per month for the last 5 months without issue.

Suddenly, today, around lunch, the event log started spewing thousands of errors:

```
The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

The email send is pretty basic. It looks like this:

```
using (var client = new SmtpClient(host, port))
            {
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
                client.EnableSsl = true;
                client.Send(message);
            }
```

Host is amazon ses server, port is 25, and username and password are the smtp credentials you are given from amazon. Just to double check I created new username and password credentials and recompiled the software, but I still have the same issue.

I am decent at software but I have never worked with certs, and I have no idea how they work. All I know is the box that the emails are being sent from has a valid Digi Cert certificate and it doesn't look like anything has changed on our end.

Can someone help me resolve this or at least ask the right question?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the SSL certificate that is being presented is invalid.  That could be for any number of reasons.  If the hostname ('Alternate DNS' address) in the cert doesn't match the address you're connecting to, you'll get this error.  The cert might not be valid according to the expiration date of the cert.  The certificate issuer might no longer be trusted.  The certificate may have been revoked and is in a revoked list somewhere.

What address are you trying to connect to, and what does that certificate look like?

Comment: I guess that's what is confusing to me. As far as I'm aware there are three connections possible.

Server that sends API request to email server.
Email server that uses the smtp client to send to amazon's server.

The server that sends the email is the one throwing that error. Does that mean the problem is with the original requesting server, the email server, or the amazon server in which I am connecting to when I send the email?

Comment: And to clarify, all of MY servers involved have valid signed digi cert that does not expire for at least a year. I checked by using the internet browser.

Comment: If your servers have valid certs, and your servers are showing this error in the event logs, then it's some resource that your servers are connecting to that is no longer presenting a valid cert.  You're going to have to do the work to figure out what specific connection is having the issue.  Add a try/catch around all places you connect to a remote machine, and log if you hit the exception (and rethrow so you don't swallow an exception when you shouldn't).  Then you can figure out which connection has the issue, and then probe more into that.